# JavaScript string is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

When working on a page whenever I call on my second function, validateNumber(), I get a "typeError: String is not a function" message can anyone explain to me why this message is occuring? My code is as follows:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  function validateLetter(dataEntry) {
    try {
      var textInput = dataEntry.value;
      var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g);
      if (textInput != replacedInput)
        throw "You can only enter letters into this field.";

      dataEntry.value = replacedInput;
    } catch (textInputError) {
      window.alert(textInputError)
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

function validateNumber(dataEntry) {
  try {
    var textInput = dataEntry.value;
    var replacedInput = textInput(/[^0-9]/g);
    if (textInput != replacedInput)
      throw "You can only enter numbers into this field.";
  } catch (numberInputError) {
    window.alert(numberInputError)
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validateInput(dataEntry) {
    if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft INternet Explorer")
      var enteredKey = dataEntry.keyCode;
    else if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
      var eneteredKey = dataEntry.charCode;
  }
  /* ]] */
  < /script>
```

```html
<form action="validateTheCharacters" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="dataEntry">
  <p>Enter your mother's maiden name:
    <input type="text" id="letter1" name="letter1" onkeypress="validateLetter(this)">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the city you were born in:
    <input type="text" id="letter2" name="letter2" onkeypress="validateLetter(this)">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the street you grew up on:
    <input type="text" id="letter3" name="letter3" onkeypress="validateLetter(this)">
  </p>

  <p>Enter your phone number:
    <input type="text" id="number1" name="number1" onkeypress="validateNumber(this)">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the year you were born:
    <input type="text" id="number2" name="number2" onkeypress="validateNumber(this)">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the number of siblings you have:
    <input type="text" id="number3" name="number3" onkeypress="validateNumber(this)">
  </p>

  <p>
    <button type="reset" value="Reset Form">Reset Form</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: That is an inappropriate use of *try..catch*. If you want to see if the value is all digits, then: `/^\d+$/.test(string)` will return true if *string* contains only digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost certain this is the problem:

```
var textInput = dataEntry.value;
var replacedInput = textInput(/[^0-9]/g);
```

if `textInput` is a string you cannot pass parameters to it as if it were a function, instead:

```
var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""); // dependening in what you are trying to achieve of course
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out after you did I looked back over the code and I realized that the .replace was used in the previous function, that is why the first one worked and the second did not.

Answer (score 2):

```
var replacedInput = textInput(/[^0-9]/g);
```

That's not how you do search and replace in Javascript.

It's not quite clear what you intended here, but if you wanted to remove non-digits from the string, you'd do that using `String.replace()`:

```
var replacedInput = textInput.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
```

That being said, an easier way of accomplishing this check would be to skip the replacement entirely and just use `String.match()` instead:

```
var textInput = dataEntry.value;
if (textInput.match(/[^0-9]/))
    throw "You can only enter letters into this field.";
dataEntry.value = textInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider isolating functionality so that functions like *validateLetter* simply validate that the string they are passed contains only letters, then have the caller function work out what to do if the return value is true or not.

In that case, you end up with very much simpler functions:

```
function validateLetters(s) {
  return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(s);
}

function validateNumbers(s) {
  return /^\d+$/.test(s);
}
```

To validate an input, you can add a class to say what type of validation it should have, e.g.

```
<input name="letter3" class="letter" onkeypress="validateLetter(this)">
```

Then the *validateInput* function can determine which validation function to call based on the class:

```
function validateInput(element) {

  var value = element.value;

  // If has class letter, validate is only letters
  if (/(\s|^)letter(\s|$)/i.test(element.className)) {

    // validate only if there is a value other than empty string
    if (!validateLetters(value) && value != '') {
      alert('Please enter only letters');
    }
  }

  // If has class number, validate is only numbers
  if (/(\s|^)number(\s|$)/i.test(element.className)) {

    // validate only if there is a value other than empty string
    if (!validateNumbers(element.value) && value != '') {
      alert('Please enter only numbers');
    }
  }
}
```

Note that keypress is not a good event to use for validation as data can be entered without pressing any keys (e.g. paste from the context menu or drag and drop). Also, the listener doesn't see the value resulting from the keypress, it sees the previous value.

You really only need to perform validation when the form is submitted. Until then, why do you care what the values are? Allow the user to make mistakes and fix them themselves without being pestered by alerts (onscreen hints are really useful). Spend some time using your forms to enhance their usability (I realise this is probably not a production form, but names can have characters other than the letters a to z, e.g. *von Braun* and *O'Reilly*).

Lastly, form controls rarely need an ID, the name is usually sufficient to identify them if required (and they must have a name to be successful, so most have a name already). A bit of play HTML from the OP:

```
<form>
  <p>Enter your mother's maiden name:
    <input name="letter1" class="letter" onkeypress="validateInput(this)">
  </p>
  <p>Enter the number of siblings you have:
    <input name="number3" class="number" onkeypress="validateInput(this)">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="reset">
  </p>
</form>
```